# How to make Vutify VMenu right aligned?

Tags: vuetify.js

I need to make right aligned v-menu with "attach" option.

Template:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <h1>VMenu bug with "right" option</h1>
    <div class="place"></div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-btn
             color="primary"
             dark
             @click="show = !show"
             >
        Dropdown
      </v-btn>
    </div>
    <v-menu attach=".place" v-model="show" :right="true">
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            @click=""
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    show: false,
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' },
    ],
  }),
})
```

I expect right aligned menu in ".place" element. But the menu is left aligned. Also top border of menu is under the ".place" element. It is strange. How can I fix it?

[Demo](https://codepen.io/itelmenko/pen/WNQOYrj)

Comment: what you are trying to achieve, can you attach screenshot or mock, You want content inside v-menu to be right aligned or you are facing issue with the v-menu position due to attach

Comment: @chans I try to move the menu to right border of page when I use "attach" option. Something like this https://ibb.co/ssHjYn1

Comment: Do you want something like the same image, when you click on button, it should show menu at right border of page. Am I right?

Comment: @chans, yeah. Is "right" option for this goal ?

Comment: "right" is something different , it doesn't work for your requirement

Comment: what different?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Vuetify 3 and I had the same problem. I solved it by using

```html
<v-menu location="bottom end">
```

*See :*
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#location
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/overlays/#location-strategies

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to align the content of v-menu to right border of the page

Here is the working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/OJyjWmX

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <h1>VMenu bug with "right" option</h1>
    <div>
      <div id="attachMenu" style="float: right;position: relative;width: 134px;left: 27px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-btn
             color="primary"
             dark
             @click="show = !show"
             >
        Dropdown
      </v-btn>
    </div>
    <v-menu attach="#attachMenu" v-model="show" :right="true">
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            @click=""
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    show: false,
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' },
    ],
  }),
})
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I now about float. But I need correct way to do it with vuetify. Without hardcoded width property for container.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?, please explain with the example, what is the issue you are facing with the above implementation and expectation

Comment: Create a dynamic component using above logic and use it everywhere

Comment: I have created own component based on v-menu. It use "right" css option with position. But I am not sure it is correct way. I thing "right" option must work. I see correct way for v-menu. Or comnfirmation that is a bug.

Comment: If that is a bug, please register as bug in Vuetify github repo, thye will give you the solution

Comment: Well, you where almost there, the correct option is "left"

Answer (score 0):

You almost got the right solution, the position with the `right` and  `left` prop is inverted

So this is what you need to do:

```html
<v-menu attach=".place" v-model="show" left>
```